# Python - How to connect SQLAlchemy to existing database in memory

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm creating my DB from an existing shema and it's stored in `:memory:`.

```
db = Database(filename=':memory:', schema='schema.sql')
db.recreate()
```

I now want to "link" this to SQL Alchemy. Followed different methods but could not get it right.

My current attempt stands as follow:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')

Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
User = Base.classes.user

session = Session(engine)
```

Much like the other stuff I tried this will throw `AttributeError: user`.

How can I have this work together?

Comment: Is `db.recreate()` a Flask thing?

Comment: @GordThompson no it's how I apply my own schema, only this code inside:  `with open(self.schema) as fin: self.conn.cursor().executescript(fin.read())  `

Answer (score 9):

The relevant part of the documentation is here: https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html .

If you use `:memory:` then every connection will have its own memory database. The trick is to use a *named* in memory database with the [**URI** format](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html?highlight=uri#uri-connections), like the following

```
import random
import string
import sqlite3

# creating a random name for the temporary memory DB
sqlite_shared_name = "test_db_{}".format(
            random.sample(string.ascii_letters, k=4)
        )

create_engine(
   "sqlite:///file:{}?mode=memory&cache=shared&uri=true".format(
        sqlite_shared_name))
```

1. the format is a URI as stated by the query string parameter `uri=true` (see SQLAlchemy documentation)
2. it is a memory DB with `mode=memory`
3. it can be shared among various connection with `cache=shared`

If you have another connection, then you can use more or less the same connection string. For instance, for getting the connection to that same DB in memory using python's `sqlite` module, you can drop the `uri=true` from the query string (and the dialect part `sqlite:///`) and pass it as argument:

```
dest = sqlite3.connect(
            "file:{}?mode=memory&cache=shared".format(sqlite_shared_name), 
            uri=True)
```