# Table created with alembic migration using sqlite memory cannot be found

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm creating a table with an alembic migration using an in-memory sqlite connection. The migration is successful, but when I try to load the table with sqlalchemy, it isn't found.

This does not happen with I use a file for sqlite. I'm wondering if the alembic migration is really a separate process call that uses different memory from the app.

```
import sqlalchemy as db

DB_CONNECTION_URL = 'sqlite:///'
engine = db.create_engine(DB_CONNECTION_URL)
connection = engine.connect()
metadata = db.MetaData()

from alembic.config import Config
import alembic.command

config = Config('alembic.ini')
config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', DB_CONNECTION_URL)
config.attributes['connection'] = connection
alembic.command.upgrade(config, 'head')

print('upgrade completed')

print(metadata.tables.keys())

tasks = db.Table('tasks', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

The print statement for the tables will be an empty array, and the attempt to load the table will result in a table-not-found error.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62502827/5320906) answer your question?

Comment: @snakecharmerb YES!