# Mocking database calls in python using pytest-mock

Tags: python-3.x, database, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I have this function defined:

```
def count_occurrences(cursor, cust_id):
    cursor.execute("SELECT count(id) FROM users WHERE customer_id = %s", (cust_id))
    total_count = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    if total_count == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I want to unit test it, for that I need to mock the database call here.

How can this be done using pytest, mock?

Answer (score 10):

So this is relatively straightforward to test since your function takes a cursor object which we can substitute with a [Mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) object. Then all we have to do is [configure](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.configure_mock) our mock cursor to return different data to test the different scenarios we have.

In the case of your tests there are two possible outcomes, `True` or `False`. So we provide different return values for `fetchone` to test both of these outcomes as shown below using [`pytest.mark.parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/parametrize.html).

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("count,expected", 
    [(0, True), (1, False), (25, False), (None, False)]
)
def test_count_occurences(count, expected):
    mock_cursor = MagicMock()
    mock_cursor.configure_mock(
        **{
            "fetchone.return_value": [count]
        }
    )

    actual = count_occurrences(mock_cursor, "some_id")
    assert actual == expected
```

When we run it we see that four separate tests are ran, against all the inputs provided.

```
collected 4 items                                                                                                

test_foo.py::test_count_occurences[0-True] PASSED                                                          [ 25%]
test_foo.py::test_count_occurences[1-False] PASSED                                                         [ 50%]
test_foo.py::test_count_occurences[25-False] PASSED                                                        [ 75%]
test_foo.py::test_count_occurences[None-False] PASSED                                                      [100%]

=============================================== 4 passed in 0.07s ================================================
```