# Mocking a SQLAlchemy Row object in Pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, pytest, python-asyncio

I've read some answers on this website which talk about mocking SQLAlchemy objects using dictionaries. Such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60080521/how-would-you-unit-test-this-sqlalchemy-core-query-function). However, I want to not have a dictionary, but an actual SQLALchemy `Table` object instantiated.

Let me explain with sample code.

This is the `User` table (I've shown only 2 columns but there are others)

```
User = Table(
    "User",
    Base.metadata,
    Column(
        "id",
        BigInteger,
        primary_key=True,
        autoincrement=True,
    ),
    Column("name", String(length=100), nullable=False),
)
```

This is the function that I'm testing

```
async def fetch_users(self, conn: AsyncConnection) -> User:
    results = await conn.execute(select(User))
    return results.all()
```

This function is called in a controller and there are other service/repository classes in that flow, but to explain how the return value of the above function is used, it's kind of like this in `user_service.py`.

```
users = await user_repository.fetch_users(conn=conn)
for user in users:
    json_response["owner"] = user.name
    json_response["id"] = user.id
    .
    .
    .
    some other attributes of the `User` table
```

Now, I have a test case written for the controller like so

```
app = FastAPI()
@pytest_asyncio.fixture()
def client():
    with TestClient(app=app) as c:
        yield c

class TestUser:
    USER_FETCH_URL = "/users"

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    @patch("repositories.users.UserRepository.fetch_users")
    async def test_fetch_users(self, mock_fetch_users, client):
        mock_fetch_users.return_value = ???

        response = client.get(self.USER_FETCH_URL)
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

I don't know what the `return_value` of `mock_fetch_users` should be.
When I do `User(id=11, name="David")`, it throws an error - `TypeError: 'Table' object is not callable`.

1. I know I can put a dictionary for the `return_value`, like `{"name": "David", "id": 11}`, but my service layer code which accesses by `.id` and `.name` will fail when it's called by the test case.
2. I also know that I can change the service layer code to access by square brackets. Square brackets will work for the SQLAlchemy `Row` object (i.e., when the function is called in the usual flow for customers), as well as when I am running my test case using a mocked `dict`. So, `user_service.py` will now have

```
for user in users:
    json_response["owner"] = user["name"]
    json_response["id"] = user["id"]
    .
    .
    .
    some other attributes of the `User` table
```

But this is not very readable. I'd prefer to have the `.id` format instead.

So, I wanted to know if there's any way I can mock/instantiate a `Row` object with dummy data or something. My purpose is to make the service class function work for both normal API calls triggered by customers as well as the test cases I've written, while also retaining readability of the format.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Mock`s to emulate the Row objects? I had a similar need and solved it using `Mock`.

In my case, I had an `Artist` row object, made of 2 columns: `name` & `path_to_bio`. My logic was: after retrieving an artist from DB, I needed to acess its `path_to_bio`. This is how I solved it:

```
artist_entity = Mock()
artist_entity.name.return_value = "Alicia Keys"
artist_entity.path_to_bio.return_value = "path/to/bio/alicia_keys.txt"
```

Now going back to your case, I think this could potentially work (haven't tried it locally):

```
from unittest.mock import Mock # <<== notice the import here

app = FastAPI()
@pytest_asyncio.fixture()
def client():
    with TestClient(app=app) as c:
        yield c

class TestUser:
    USER_FETCH_URL = "/users"

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    @patch("repositories.users.UserRepository.fetch_users")
    async def test_fetch_users(self, mock_fetch_users, client):
        mock_user_1 = Mock()
        mock_user_2 = Mock()

        mock_user_1.id.return_value = 1
        mock_user_1.name.return_value = "one"

        mock_user_2.id.return_value = 2
        mock_user_2.name.return_value = "two"

        mock_fetch_users.return_value = [mock_user_1, mock_user_2]

        response = client.get(self.USER_FETCH_URL)
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

Hope this can still help someone.